# Get parameter value from url by opening page as window.open(url,"_self")?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

i have opened url "pathofServer/bookingSlot.jsp?slot=Slot2"

```
var clickedSlotNo=this.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
        var url="bookingSlot.jsp";
        url +="?slot=" +clickedSlotNo;
        window.open(url,"_self");
```

the above code is part of javascript fuction present in xyz.jsp file,from this iam opening a new jsp named bookingSlot.jsp ,and i am able to open page but i am not getting how to get the value of slot in new bookingSlot.jsp.
Please help me..

Comment: have you tried `<%=request.getParameter("slot")%>` or `<c:out value="${param.slot}"/>`?

Comment: If you need the argument in JavaScript: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) SO question.

Comment: If i have another parameter with same slot ,which is used in another jsp file?Will it be an exception?just having doubt

Answer (score 0):

In your `bookingSlot.jsp` file, add following snippet:

```
<%
    String slot = request.getParameter("slot");
%>
```